# How to use webhooks?

Tags: webhooks

I am working on a project where I need to integrate the google-services(like Gmail, Gcalendar). When the user gets a mail or something added to the gCalender I need to activate some code. Can I achieve it by webhooks or need to do polling with some time duration.

If I use webhooks, how to determine which user data that I get(consider I have thousands of users).

Comment: Too broad, seek for tutorial, didn't show any codes. What did you want? Try coding first (and search in Google)!

Comment: I want to trigger some code when something happens in gmail. I'm able to do it with polling. I'm doing polling for every 10 min. Instead of doing polling, how can I achieve it through webhooks ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use webhooks to get push notifications. Webhooks are very similar to API's but they are inverted instead. For example instead of you making a call to an API you would define a callback URL in which the receiving end will then HTTP Post the information that you want, e.g name etc.

the creation or registration of a webhook will be the combination of:

--> a **Friendly name** for that webhook.

--> the **URL** where the callback should be sent

--> the **scope** of the webhook

--> the **events** to post to the URL either all events or a set of specific events.

Name: "MyWebhook"

URL: http://www.webhookapplication.com/webhookreciever

Scope: Project = .... and fixversion IN ("5.1")

Events: Updated and create etc.

You can create webhooks by first setting up an unique URL which I use RequestBin for e.g http://requestb.in/XXXXXXXX

Most Event Webhooks will notify a URL that you choose via the HTTP Post with information about events that occur.

A good example about webhooks can be found here:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/index.html

And this here will example how to use the send grid event to email:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html